# Dynamic Values in Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Template Deployment Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

Is there anyway to use dynamic values for subscription and resource group in [Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Template Deployment Task? (not YAML)](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md)

[image]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use variables in those fields.

Comment: You have saved my life!! Thank you!! I didn't know that we can rewrite autocompleted values. @DanielMann

Comment: @jojo- Glad that you have cleared the issue, please post it as an answer , so that it can be helpful for other community members, Thank you.